# Can't run 'mongod' command, says not recognized

Tags: windows, mongodb, path

I'm trying to set up a local db server on my Windows 10 x64 machine. When I try to run anything with `mongod` it doesn't run. I've already added the PATH, which is now C:/mongodb/bin (tried just C:/mongodb already). Also when I try to run mongo.exe and mongod.exe from the bin folders, the command box launches and immediately disappears, even when run as administrator. What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Windows I would recommend

1. to run cmd - Windows command prompt console
2. to navigate to the folder, where you installed mongoDB, in particular, to the `bin` subfolder. In my case the path is

   `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`
3. run `mongo --version`
4. if your installation is correct than you will have something like

   `MongoDB shell version v4.0.9<br />`

   `git version: fc525e2d9b0e4bceff5c2201457e564362909765`
5. to go to the the Windows Environment Variables (type `Environment Variables` in the WIndows search field)
6. to add mongo (`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`) to Windows PATH **Env**
7. to close cmd terminal and open again...

`mongo --version should work from any place of your Windows`

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you open a terminal and go to the mongo.exe path and run the exe from there?
Doing that the command box won't disappear and you can see if there is any error.

Comment: Doing it that way made me realize that I shouldn't have been using Powershell or Git Bash. CMD worked as it should. If you can tell me why it doesn't work in Powershell but works in CMD that would be nice. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

after add mongo.exe path into env path in windows 10 i can run this command

but not applied

**and after close terminal and vscode then restart all of them again**

Answer (score 0):

[mongod.exe location in bin folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/behH6.png)

open this file(mongod)manually .you would find some vcruntime140.dll and some others "dll file missing" error. Fix them using youtube videos. than you would be manually able to open this mongod file. than use command in terminal to load

/Users/hp/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath=/Users/hp/mongodb-data.

now this command in terminal would work